# License that forces developers to make their contributions/add-ons open source

Tags: license-recommendation

I wanna develop a software in PHP. This software I wanna put under a license which forces every person, which continues the development or makes an addon, to make it open source.

Which license would be the best and what would be the disadvantage of the license?

I tried to understand some license, but always I was confusing, what is allowd and what is forbidden.

Comment: It sounds like you want the GPL (General Public License). Third-parties that use your GPL-licensed software must publish the source code. If you are confused about something specific, please clarify your question.

Comment: Why the vote down. We should not just vote down because he programs in PHP.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Whether it is written in PHP or another language is not important, so you don't need to mention it. Your question is a bit unclear (what do you find confusing) therefore maybe it was voted down for that reason.